# Why topological ordering helps speeding shortest path finding

Tags: graph-theory

This question is just for discussing algorithms please and not for proposing algorithms. I saw very similar post to mine, but still the answer explains definitions online for topological ordering.

Regarding the problem of finding shortest paths, Dijkestras and Bellman-Ford algorithms are very popular. While both work with weighted directed graph, Bellman-Ford algorithm can work with negative edges. Dijkestra takes $O(E\log{E})$ while  Bellman-Ford algorithm takes $O(EV)$ to execute, where $E$ is the number of edges and $V$ is the number of vertices in graph $G$.

Now here comes my issue, topological ordering works by just numbering the order by which we will visit the vertices of a graph and it works with negative edges as well, so this is a pro over Dijkestra. Because of topological ordering, we speed up shortest path finding to just linear time to $O(E+V)$.

**Problem**: could you please simply explain the logic behind introducing topological sorting and how it helps cutting down complexity to just $O(E+V)$?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that Directed Acyclic Graph is assumed as input (DAG).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Thank you. I forgot to mention it's DAG. So I am just looking to know logic please if possible behind having topological sorting prior to shortest path finding of DAG please?

Comment: Well, Djiksrra’s algorithm, at least, works on all graphs. The point I was making is that topological sorting doesn’t improve the algorithm in general, only on the subset of the inputs (the DAGs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ where $E \subseteq V^2$ and both $V$ and $E$ are finite, a topological sort of $G$ is a total order $\leq$ on $V$ such that if $v \leq u$ then $(v, u) \notin E$.

Typically, a topological sort of a graph is represented by a sequence of nodes $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$, where $n = |V|$ and $\{v_1, ..., v_n\} = V$. The order is then that $v_i \leq v_j$ iff $i \leq j$.

The key constraint on a topological sort is that a topological sort exists if and only if the graph is acyclic. This means there cannot be a cycle of edges $v_1 \to v_2 \to ... \to v_n \to v_1$ in a graph with a topological sort.

Topological sorting can allow faster determination of the shortest path between two nodes. To find the shortest path between nodes `r` and `q` in the weighted graph `(V, E, weight)`, we execute the following algorithm.

```
Let v_1, v_2, ..., v_n be a topological sort of (V, E, weight);
For each i from 1 to n:
   If v_i = r:
      Let dist_i = 0;
   Else:
      Let dist_i = the minimum of dist_k + w, 
          taken over all edges of the form (v_k, v_i) with weight w;
   If v_i = q:
      return dist_i;
```

Here is a brief proof that the algorithm is correct.

I claim that after the $i$th iteration of the for-loop of the form `For each i from 1 to n`, for all $j$ such that $j \leq i$, the value `dist_j` is the length of the shortest path from `r` to `v_j`. If there is no shortest path, we say the length of the shortest path is `infinity`.

We proceed by strong induction on `i`.

Case `i = 0`: This holds vacuously.

Case `i = c + 1`: In this case, we see that the value of `dist_j` is correct for all `j <= c`; that is, for all `j < i`.

Any path from `r` to `v_i` which contains at least one edge must end with some edge of the form `(v_k, v_i)` with weight `w`. So a path with at least one edge from `r` to `v_i` consists of a path from `r` to `v_k` together with an edge `v_k` to `v_i`. So the minimal weight of a path from `r` to `v_i` with at least one edge will be

$$ \min\limits_{(v_k, v_i) \text{ an edge with weight } w, p \text{ a path from } r \text{ to } v_k} w + length(p) = \min\limits_{(v_k, v_i) \text{ an edge with weight } w} [w + \min\limits_{p \text{ a path from } r \text{ to } v_k} length(p)]$$

Now fix some edge $(v_k, v_i)$ with weight $w$. We know it cannot be the case that $i \leq k$; therefore, $k < i$. Then we know going into this iteration that

$$dist_k = \min\limits_{p \text{ a path from } r \text{ to } v_k} length(p)$$

And so the minimum we're looking for is

$$\min\limits_{(v_k, v_i) \text{ an edge with weight } w} w + dist_k$$

Which is exactly what our code does.

In the case where $v_i = r$, we see that because the graph is acyclic, the only path from $v_i$ to itself is the empty path with weight $0$. This is why we include this clause.

Thus, we have proved the correctness of the algorithm.

Note that the critical part of the proof was observing that we had already correctly computed $dist_k$ for all $k$ such that $(v_k, v_i)$ is an edge by the time we get around to computing the value of $dist_i$. This is absolutely essential for the correctness of the algorithm. If we don't have a topological sort, then we don't get this guarantee of correctness.

Why is this algorithm `O(E + V)`? Let's consider that there is an implicit inner loop running when we compute $dist_i$ for $v_i \neq r$. In this implicit inner loop, we iterate over all edges ending in node $v_i$. Now each edge ends with exactly 1 node. Thus, we will iterate over each given edge at most 1 time. This is why the inner loop will execute `O(E)` times in total across all executions of the outer loop. And thus the whole thing will be `O(E + V)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You used index $k$, can you please add what is this $k$?

Comment: @Avra When I'm discussing finding the minimum value of $(w + dist_k)$ in the computation of $dist_i$, I'm iterating over all edges into the node $v_i$. $k$ is just the index of the starting node of the edge - the edge is from $v_k$ to $v_i$ and has weight $w$.